# Representing revenue as a quadratic function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I am trying to represent the following with a quadratic formula I believe I have done it correctly and im just wondering if I am right.

Eastern gym charges its adult members $\$50$ monthly for a membership. The club has $600$ adult members. Eastern gym estimates that for each $5$ increase in the monthly fee, it will lose $50$.

my answer would be

$y=(600-50x)(50+5x)$ where x is the number of people is this correct?

Comment: Do you really mean that $x$ is the “number of people”? Usually revenue is a function of price

Comment: Well, not quite.  Here $x$ is the "number of increases in the monthly fee". not the number of people.  The number of members would then be $600-50x$.

Comment: make sense, thanks!

Comment: You should define $x$ carefully.  Your expression is correct if $x$ is measured in units of $\$5$.  If it is measured in dollars, the coefficients should be a factor of $5$ less.